# IIF Statement Correct Syntax

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to get the correct syntax for an IIF statement.   Currently the statement reads:
=First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall")

However, if the result of the data is MAIN then I want it to null.  As in I dont want it to print/call if it result is MAIN.   How would do I this?   This is within SSRS Report Writer.

Comment: Why are you using FIRST - is your field grouped by location number? Location*Number* can be `Main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS, NOTHING is used for a NULL value. Though for any text, an empty string ( `""`) works just as well.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall") <> "MAIN", 
    First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall"), 
    NOTHING)
```

This will check the first row of Location Number to see if it is MAIN, if not, it will put the Location Number otherwise it will be empty (NULL/NOTHING). You could also use `""` instead of NOTHING in this case.

Updated

```
=IIF(First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall") <> "MAIN" 
     AND First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall") <> "PRIMARY",
    First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall"), 
    NOTHING)
```

Comment: This functions exactly as desired.   If there were limiters other than MAIN  how would I add them.  For example, "PRIMARY" is also used a lot.   How I would incorporate that?

Comment: @RonBizzle - If you also wanted PRIMARY to be blank, you would need to add an AND to the IIF statement for the primary so it reads `If not MAIN and not PRIMARY then...`
`=IIF(First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall") <> "MAIN" and Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall") <> "PRIMARY", 
    First(Fields!LocationNumber.Value, "dsServiceCall"), 
    NOTHING)`

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error when attempting to preview the SSRS report.   Do I need the entire gray section or just the =IIF  and so on.

Comment: @RonBizzle  Ugh - it looks like I overwrote part when copy/parting in the comment box. I updated the answer with the fixed expression.